# What is the performance hit of using TLS with apache?

Tags: performance, apache, encryption, ssl

How much of a performance hit will running everything over TLS do to my server? I would assume this is completely ignorable in this day and age? I heard once that servers today could encrypt gigabytes of data per second, is that true? And if so, is it linearly scalable so that if top speed is 10GB/second, encrypting 1GB would take 0.1 second?

I'm not in some kind of pickle with any admin over this (yet). I'm just curious and if I can mostly ignore the hit, why not just encrypt everything?

Comment: @RobbieGee: you mean *TLS* not TSL. May want to change your title/body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Performance Analysis of TLS Web Servers (pdf)](http://www.isoc.org/isoc/conferences/ndss/02/papers/coarfa.pdf), a paper written at Rice University, covered this topic back in 2002, and they came to this conclusion:

> Apache TLS without the AXL300 served between 149 hits/sec and 259 hits/sec for the CS trace, and between 147 hits/sec and 261 hits/sec for the Amazon trace. This confirms that TLS incurs a substantial cost and reduces the throughput by 70 to 89% relative to the insecure Apache.

So without the AXL300 board, which offloads encryption, there was a reduction in throughput of 70-89% on a PIII-933MHz. However, they note in the next section that as CPU speeds increase, the throughput is expected to increase accordingly. So since 2002, you may find that there is no noticeable difference for your workload.